# Trying to capture group in javascript regex (port from c#)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex

```
var mregex = /(\$m[\w|\.]+)/g;
string mstring= "$m.x = $m.y";
```

So basically capture each instance of $m.[+ any number of alphanumeric or . until another character or the end]

I have this working in C# but I'm trying to port it over to javascript, so dropped the name capture.

```
var match = mregexp.exec(mstring);
```

match has
    0: "$m.x"
    1: "$m.x"  // not $m.y as I would have expected.

What am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at how `exec` works and how to get multiple matches with a global flag at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You regular expression just matches once. The `[0]` element of the return array is the entire matched substring. The `[1]` element is the first group, which in your case is the same.  You'd have to call `.exec()` again to get it to find the second instance.

You can pass a function to `.replace()`, which I personally like:

```
mstring.replace(mregexp, function(_, group) {
  console.log( group );
});
```

That'd show you both matched groups. (The function is passed arguments that are of the same nature as the elements of the returned array from `.exec()`.)

Comment: thanks pointy. it makes sense, just when i saw the returned object with two elements assumed they were the results. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to repeat `mregexp.exec()` until it returns `null`.

```
var match = []; //initialize a new array
while(mregexp.exec(mstring)){
    match.push(mregexp[1]);
}
```

For Javascript's flavor of regexen see http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call `mstring.match(mregexp)` to return all of the matches, but you only see the matched substrings (in which case you could simplify `mregexp` to `/\$m[\w.]+/g`).